# Where is AssertionError defined in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, assertion, expect.js

I'd like to have my unit tests assert that a particular function call throws an AssertionError specifically when expected, rather than that it throws an exception at all. The assertion library (expect) supports such a thing by passing an exception constructor in, but I can't seem to find where, if anywhere, the AssertionError constructor is exported. Is it intended to be an internal class only and not exposed to us? [The docs](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) contain numerous references to it, but no links.

I have a super hacky way:

```
let AssertionError;

try {
    const assert = require("assert");

    assert.fail();
}
catch (ex) {
    AssertionError = ex.constructor;
}
```

but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Assertion error class is defined here:

```
assert.AssertionError
```

*It can be useful while testing and AsserionError is expected result:

```
assert.throws( FunctionThatShouldThrow_AssertionError, assert.AssertionError )
```

Answer (score 0):

After a research in the Nodejs github repo, I can tell you it is here: 
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/c75f87cc4c8d3699e081d37bb5bf47a70d830fdb/lib/internal/errors.js

AssertionError is defined like this :

```js
class AssertionError extends Error {
  constructor(options) {
    if (typeof options !== 'object' || options === null) {
      throw new exports.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'options', 'object');
    }
    var { actual, expected, message, operator, stackStartFunction } = options;
    if (message) {
      super(message);
    } else {
      if (actual && actual.stack && actual instanceof Error)
        actual = `${actual.name}: ${actual.message}`;
      if (expected && expected.stack && expected instanceof Error)
        expected = `${expected.name}: ${expected.message}`;
      if (util === null) util = require('util');
      super(`${util.inspect(actual).slice(0, 128)} ` +
        `${operator} ${util.inspect(expected).slice(0, 128)}`);
    }

    this.generatedMessage = !message;
    this.name = 'AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]';
    this.code = 'ERR_ASSERTION';
    this.actual = actual;
    this.expected = expected;
    this.operator = operator;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, stackStartFunction);
  }
}
```

If I were you, I would not redefined AssertionError, that is very, very hacky. I think your best bet is to extend that class to MyAssertionError or to create a twin than extends error.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm...I take it from the `lib/internal` in the path that it's not intended for public consumption. Damn.

Comment: As for my snippet above, I'm not redefining `AssertionError`, just getting a reference to it. I'm not sure what you mean by "extend that class to MyAssertionError". I'm using Node's built-in `assert` library, so I can't tell it what error class to use, it'll always use `AssertionError`.

Comment: @TurnerHayes - is my previous answer is what you are looking for?